# Creating dynamic Variables with a function

Tags: powershell

My Code

```
$SQLResults = Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $SeverInstance-Database $DataBase -query $Query

$Results = $SQLResults | gm | where { $_.membertype -eq "Property" }



        foreach($Name in $Results)
        {
            $var = $Name.name
            New-Variable -name "$var" -Value $var
        }



function reset-variables($Results)
{
    get-variable | where {$_.name -match $_.value} | foreach Remove-Variable -Force
}
```

Using PowerShell

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      0      10586  117

I wanted to create a set of functions that would dynamically create and remove variables.  This was just for creating better code for pester test integration.  The issue I am coming across is that the following code is giving off different weird exceptions like  `Unrecognized escape sequence` which I have yet to ever see.  The permissions are correct I am getting results stored in `$SQLResults` and `$Results` however when I call my function and pass in `$Results` nothing will happen.  However if I run the internal commands like  `get-variable | where {$_.name -match $_.value} | foreach Remove-Variable -Force` it throws a `cannot be resolved to a method` exception.  But it removes the variables!

Thank you for your time.

***EDIT
I am able to get the correct creation behavior

```
$Results = $SQLResults | gm | where { $_.membertype -eq "Property" }
$b = $Results.name
$c = [string]$b -split " "

        foreach($Name in $Results)
        {
            $var = $Name.name
            New-Variable -name "$var" -Value $var
        }
```

and also the correct removal behavior

```
foreach($i in $c){
    Remove-Variable $i
    }
```

Please help me to understand either A) how to create a function that can use these behaviors or B) why scope wont allow for these to work internally to if a function is created  I keep getting the following error

```
Remove-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'apple'.
At line:4 char:9
+Remove-Variable $i
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (apple:String) [Remove-Variable ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVariableCommand
```

Despite the variable $apple existing with a value of "apple" when I parse through $c (which includes apples) outside the function it will remove it but not inside.

Comment: Your `ForEach-Object` in `Reset-Variables` is pointless.  Just pipe directly to `Remove-Variable`

Comment: I understand, however when I do that it doesnt work, but when I pipe the foreach it still errors but the behavior removes the variable which is confusing.  Syntactically is there anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the intent of `reset-variables`? You're using `$Results` as parameter, but you are not using it inside your function. I guess you want to remove the variables you've created via `create-variables`. Correct?

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is bad practice. Don't do this. Period.

Comment: I'm coming from JavaScript where this is common practice. Can you cite me a source on why this is "bad"  practice in powershell? Thanks

Comment: I will ask you a counter question. Why do you feel that you need to do this? You have taken an object and made a bunch of objects from it. How does this make for better Pester integration? Disregarding the fact that the code you have posted would actually lose all the actual data, anything that you would do with these new variables is possible with the original object. Again, how does this make Pester integration better?

Comment: For clarification, there is a unique situation where a very large volume of untested code will need to be tested. Regardless that has nothing to do with the execution of the code itself where I would like to stay on topic.  I have changed the code to get the correct behavior outside of the functions please see the updated post